# c++ ofstream write to a file the value not the address of object

Tags: c++, vector, ofstream

So I have a vector of shared pointers to objects of employees:

```
static std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Employee>> myVector;
```

And I want to write the employee objects I have stored in there to a file:

```
ofstream myFile;
myFile.open("test.bin", ios::binary);

if (file_out.is_open()){
    file_out << myEmployee.myVector[0] << endl;//works just fine i get 0057BCC8
    file_out << *myEmployee.myVector[0] << endl;//deference doesnt show anything
}
```

how do i dereference to get the values of my oject??

Comment: Is Employee actually printable?

Comment: You have a vector of pointers. `myEmployee.myVector[0]` is a pointer. `*myEmployee.myVector[0]` is what it points to.

Answer (score 0):

OKAY finally i figured it out im so stupid, that I overlooked this.  Yes employee can be printed out because i overloaded the operator<<, however that is not my problem.

Because my vector is holding shared pointers to employee objects i have to use the -> operator like so

```
if (file_out.is_open()){
        for (std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i != myEmployee.myVector.size(); i++){
            file_out << myEmployee.myVector[i]->name << endl;
            file_out << myEmployee.myVector[i]->id << endl;
```

....

Comment: You might want to check your `<<` overload because `file_out << *myEmployee.myVector[0] << endl;` should have worked